# NavigationBar Hidding issue on Back

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationbar

On `View1` I hide the `navigationBar` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Then I navigate to `View2` where I show the `navigationBar`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    self.title = @"Title";
}
```

But on back to `View1` again, the `navigationBar` doesn't hide, even if I did tried to hide it after the `pushViewController` in `View2`

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:View1 animated:YES];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

I also tried to hide the navigation from `viewWillAppear` in View1 and it hides it, but there is an ugly delay and I don't find it as a good practice.

So can anyone help me with this issue, how can I hide correctly the `navigationBar` on back to `View1`?

Comment: viewDidLoad is only called once.  you'll need to put it in viewWillAppear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice to do what you want is putting bellow in your first viewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: on ViewWillDisappear on View 2 works great. It hides. I haven't thought of ViewWillDisappear so thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: This is what I said I am doing but, it has a second or so delay and you can see the navigation bar. It's not ok for what I'm trying to do. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but you need to write like this:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

first, then write

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:View1 animated:YES];
```

Comment: then write two function for hide and show in AppDelegate..then call those methods..whenever you want...

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewController1` is not going to get allocated again and so viewDidLoad is not going to get called.
 You can do it in `viewWillAppear` though. But if you are saying that there is a delay, you can do one more thing.

You can get the reference ofViewController1 in ViewController2. Suppose ViewController1 is the first controller in the navigation controller, then do this:

```
//ViewController2.m
- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender{
 ViewController1 *view1 = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[view1.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: It is right this way, is just that I didn't want to put a custom back button. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I would have upvoted your answer 'cause it's good, but sorry, it doesn't let me. Have a great day! :)

Answer (score -1):

See when you are pushing `View2` from `View2` in `navigation stack` than `View1` doesn't gets `deallocated`. it is there in in the stack. So when you popping out `View2` that time `View1` viewDidLoad won't get called. so your code `setNavigationBarHidden` to hide navigation bar doesn't executes. So put that code to `ViewWillAppear` or `ViewDidAppear` because these methods gets called every time View appears.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: He said he already did it but there is an ugly delay so he needs some other solution.